# How to prevent unwanted users from accessing a public website?

Tags: security, web, authorization

Many unwanted users are creating fake accounts on our website to pester us.
What can we do?

Answer (score 3):

Add a [captcha](http://www.captcha.net/) to keep out robots, then monitor IP addresses for multiple create attempts and block the ones that make more than 1 or 2 (depending on nature of site).

If you give us your web service software name (IIS, glassfish, tomcat, etc...) there may be some more specific addons that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can require all new accounts to be manually accepted by an admin before they're activated. Checking the IP's for multiples is okay, but ineffective if they're using proxies.

Generally, you just have to make it enough of a pain so that they get bored and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the websites do these things to prevent that.

- Create an email verification while registering.
- Add Captcha to register form.
- Do not accept emails from temporary/disposable email services.
- Monitor IP addresses and block them from creating multiple accounts.